# TFS checking in the code without getting the latest version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, version-control, checkin

If I check-in file to TFS repository without getting the latest version (i.e, without merging the changes on my side first) then, is one of the version bound to loose? Let us assume `v1` is the version on TFS that I forgot to get and merge before checking in, and assume `v2` be the version that I checked in. Suppose `v1` exists on another machine, can I go ahead re check-in `v1` without getting the latest version on the second machine, and redo get-latest and merge on primary machine to have everything recover? What are my options to minimize the loss? What happens if I did not have the second machine with `v1`? Are there any mechanism in TFS that prevent me from checking in my version without getting the latest from the TFS first?

Comment: There is the version on the server and the version on your machine.  If the versions are different, you MUST merge before checking in.  Let's say there are two of you trying to check in at the same time.  Whoever checks in first is the winner, and the loser has to merge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming someone have checked in v1 to TFS on another machine during you work on your machine, then you may get conflicts warning. The conflicts maybe automatically resolved, maybe request you resolve manually.

[image]